# Transforming geometry from two coordinate to three coordinates in R using sf

Tags: r, r-sf

I have two data frames with sf geometry, in which one has two coordinates and others have three coordinates, i.e, one coordinate is based on c(1,2) and another is based on c(3,4,0). I want to bind these two tables but failed because R is "expecting three coordinates". I am wondering what is the code for transforming geometry from two coordinates to three coordinates in sf? In other words, I want the first coordinate change from c(1, 2) to c(1, 2, 0).

Thanks very much for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correctly you are looking for a way to add height dimension to one of your datasets.

To do so consider the `sf::st_zm()` function with drop = F (not dropping = adding :).

For an illustration consider this example, built on three North Carolina cities (it plays well with the nc.shp that is shipped with {sf}).

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

points <- data.frame(name = c("Raleigh", "Greensboro", "Wilmington"),
                     x = c(-78.633333, -79.819444, -77.912222),
                     y = c(35.766667, 36.08, 34.223333)) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x","y"), crs=4326)

points
# Simple feature collection with 3 features and 1 field
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -79.81944 ymin: 34.22333 xmax: -77.91222 ymax: 36.08
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#         name                   geometry
# 1    Raleigh POINT (-78.63333 35.76667)
# 2 Greensboro    POINT (-79.81944 36.08)
# 3 Wilmington POINT (-77.91222 34.22333)

pts_two <- points %>% 
  st_zm(drop = F, what = "Z")

pts_two    
# Simple feature collection with 3 features and 1 field
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XYZ
# Bounding box:  xmin: -79.81944 ymin: 34.22333 xmax: -77.91222 ymax: 36.08
# z_range:       zmin: 0 zmax: 0
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#         name                       geometry
# 1    Raleigh POINT Z (-78.63333 35.76667 0)
# 2 Greensboro    POINT Z (-79.81944 36.08 0)
# 3 Wilmington POINT Z (-77.91222 34.22333 0)
```